# Android Studio preview of design is pixelated

Tags: android, android-studio

My android studio design preview is blurry. The text as well as widgets. I tried to fix it my doing the following:

Android Studio properties>Compatibility>Change High DPI settings>Override High DPI

I closed android studio and went back on it and it was sill pixelated.
Any solutions?
I need help quick because I have to start my project within a few days and I am worried that my final app will look blurry
Thank You!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJh93.png)

Comment: Anyone have an answer

Answer (score 2):

It's look like the problem comes from your computer screen resolution. if you have 1080 full hd screen and you have to set your layout and scale to 125% the design preview will pixelated.

you need to adjust the scale and layout to 100% this is for windows users.

[settings up scale and layout windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m729u.png)

[the result after changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAaB4.png)

It's late answer but for someone who faced this problems.

Comment: This issue is Clumsy bug from intellij And you have to wait until it is fixed.

Comment: Thanks ! this seems to solve the problem for now!