# Low quality of xml preview in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I was designing my layout, however the layout is in a low quality state.
How i can resolve it?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer help?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54273380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is solved at android studio version 2021.1.1 (Bumblebee) that released at 25 January 2022